# Segmentation fault at checking pointer data

Tags: c, data-structures

I trying to insert a data in a double linked list after a specified data and it shows a segment error.

```
void dllinsertafter(struct node **head,int data,int data1)
{
struct node *temp,*newnode;
newnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
newnode->data=data;
temp=*head;
while ((temp->data)!=data1)
    temp=temp->next;
newnode->next=temp->next;
temp->next->prev=newnode;
newnode->prev=temp;
temp->next=newnode;
}
```

No idea as to why the error is at while(temp->data!=data1).The structure used is common for double linked lists.

Comment: It's possible to reach the end of the list and not have `data!=25`, so `temp` gets assigned NULL (especially since you never check the value of `temp`). Segfault would arrive if you tried to use it then.

Comment: You may want to have a look at https://github.com/raymontag/Linked-Lists-in-C I've written this long time ago and my C knowledge wasn't very good but it works and may help you.

Answer (score 2):

So here are some generic thoughts:

1. You allocate memory for `temp`, and then promptly leak it.
2. In your while loop, what happens if you **never find** `data1`?

   Then for some node, `temp->next == NULL`, so then you'll assign `NULL` to `temp`, and then you'll attempt to dereference `temp`, ensuring a fault.
3. [WhozCraig noted another location for a fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24716809/segmentation-fault-at-checking-pointer-data/24716831?noredirect=1#comment38335597_24716831). What happens if `*head == NULL`. That is, you start with an empty list? In this case, you'll immediately assign `temp = NULL`, and then you'll soon attempt to dereference `temp`, ensuring a fault.

Comment: No i removed the allocation for temp.But it hardly makes a difference.How am i leaking it if i allocate memory for it?

Comment: `temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));` followed by `temp=*head;`

Comment: ok i remove it.Then again it shows the same error at the while loop.

Comment: Addon: what happens if `*head* is NULL to begin with.

Comment: @Paku: I have 3 bullet points in my answer, it doesn't appear that you've read the second or third one. (Or atleast, I don't think you have. I may be mistaken).

Comment: No i am just testing insert.Answering point 2,data1 is present is present in the list as it is initialized in another function.Similarly for point 3 the head is not null.It's a testcase.

Comment: @Paku: In that case, you'll want to provide this community with your full test case. Perhaps something with a main() and everything that we would need to try it on our own computers. At this point, I'm assuming that there is a bug (or unexpected behavior) in your test harness.

Answer (score 0):

Crash is happening if the data1 is not found. Some cases are not handled properly, change the logic as below which will solve the crash.

```
//check to prevent the crash if list is empty
if (*head == NULL)
{

    *head = newnode;
    newnode->previous = newnode->next = NULL;
}
else
{
    temp=*head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        if((temp->data)==data1)break;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    newnode->next=temp->next;
    //check to prevent the crash if data1 is last element
    if (temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp->next->prev=newnode;
    }
    newnode->prev=temp;
    temp->next=newnode;
}
```

`temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));` - This memory allocation is not required, this getting leaked at `temp=*head;`